# Bluetooth low energy writeCharacteristic return false in Nexus 5x with Android marshmallow

Tags: bluetooth, android-6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, characteristics, bluetooth-lowenergy

My app is work fine in Samsung S6 and Nexus 5 and Nexus 7 with Android 5, however, it can't work in Nexus 5x with Android 6.

---

boolean success = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

---

My app will send this command many times to set or get data from a hardware, however, it may return false after one or two command sent.(The first command will return true)

Does Android Marshmallow change something in BLE?

Answer (score 3):

A common cause of this is if you try to do more than one write or read in a row. You have to wait for the result of a previous read or write before doing the next one. For non-trivial applications this usually means setting up a job queue.

If this is not the cause then if you attach the Android source in your IDE you may be able to step through `BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic()` in the debugger and see exactly where it's returning false. The source I'm looking at has 6 places where it returns false, mostly "early outs", so it could be any one of those.

Comment: Experienced this when reading and writing at the same time when just experimenting with bluetooth le